# Ошибка: double cannot be dereferenced

Tags: java

Для решения одной задачи мне надо округлить результат деления Integer/Integer до большего целого числа (если он будет являться дробью).

Чтобы решить эту задачу я нашёл две конструкции:

Конструкция 1:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 3;
int x = (a+(b-1))/b;
```

Конструкция 2:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 3;
int x = Math.ceil((double)a / b).intValue();
```

Как я понимаю, единственно правильным будет использовать конструкцию 2, т.к. конструкция 1 работает не для всех значений (например, отрицательные b).

Проблема в том, что в своём коде при компиляции я получаю непонятную мне ошибку, на которую я не нашёл самостоятельного ответа:

> java: double cannot be dereferenced

Пример моего кода:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int h = 20;
        int up = 7;
        int down = 3;

        int predUpDays = h - up;
        int progress = up - down;

        int days = Math.ceil((double)predUpDays / progress).intValue();
        days++;

        System.out.println(days);

    }
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Почему бы не использовать первый метод с условием по знаку b? Тогда не придётся уходить на вещественную арифметику и возвращаться назад

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Math.ceil((double)predUpDays / progress)
```

вот это выражение возвращает `double`. А это "простой тип", у него нет методов и соответственно их нельзя позвать. `double` это не `Double`.

Очень похоже, что Вам нужно где то такое

```
int days = (int)Math.ceil((double)predUpDays / progress);
```

Answer (score 0):

`.intValue()` в вашем случае это метод класса `Double` попробуйте как в ответе @KoVadim либо так

```
int days = Double.valueOf(Math.ceil((double) predUpDays / progress)).intValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам правильно уже ответили, как нужно исправить код. Если вы так и не увидели ошибку, то разбейте эту строку:

```
int days = Math.ceil((double)predUpDays / progress).intValue();
```

следующим образом:

```
double quotient = (double) predUpDays / progress;
double ceilingResult = Math.ceil(quotient);
int days = ceilingResult.intValue();
```

Совершенно очевидно, что третья строчка не может быть выполнена, так как у переменной `double ceilingResult` не может быть не то что метода `.intValue()`, а вообще каких бы то ни было методов.